# use of searchExecutor

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, keywordquery

I'm trying to use the search for sharepoint 2013 so I use searchExecutor. 
My issue is when I execute this line, I get an exception

```
ResultTableCollection searchResults = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(kquery);
```

Here is the complete example

```
// get the query and settings service proxy
                SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();
                // get the search service application proxy by name
                SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("Search Service Application");

                KeywordQuery kquery = new KeywordQuery(searchProxy);
                kquery.IgnoreAllNoiseQuery = false;
                kquery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
                kquery.RowsPerPage = Convert.ToInt32(itemPerPage);
                kquery.RowLimit = Convert.ToInt32(itemPerPage);
                kquery.StartRow = (currentPage * Convert.ToInt32(itemPerPage)) + 1;
                string[] cols = queryCol.Split(';');
                foreach (string c in cols)
                {
                    kquery.SelectProperties.Add(c);
                }
                kquery.QueryText = strKey.Trim();
                int ce = kquery.SortList.Count;
                switch (dir.ToLower())
                {
                    case "ascending":
                        kquery.SortList.Add(colSort, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection.Ascending);
                        break;
                    case "descending":
                        kquery.SortList.Add(colSort, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SortDirection.Descending);
                        break;
                }
                //kquery.ResultTypes |= ResultType.RelevantResults;
                //ResultTableCollection searchResults = kquery.Execute();
                //ResultTable queryResultsTable = searchResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
                SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                Utils.writeDBLog("", "searchExecutor","" );
                ResultTableCollection searchResults = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(kquery);
                Utils.writeDBLog("", "searchResults", "");
                var queryResultsTables = searchResults.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                Utils.writeDBLog("", "queryResultsTables", "");
                var resultTable = queryResultsTables.FirstOrDefault();
                Utils.writeDBLog("", "resultTable", "");

                DataTable dtTemp = resultTable.Table;

                //DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
                //dtTemp.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
                sourceDataTable = CompleteDatatable(dtTemp);
                //nbResult = queryResultsTable.TotalRows;
                nbResult = resultTable.TotalRows;
                Utils.writeDBLog("", "nbResult", "nbResult: " + nbResult);
```

In SharePoint 2010, I used the line in comment and it worked correctly but in 2013 it's obsolete so I want to use searchExecutor.

For information I get this in my catch block

> La recherche a rencontré un problème qui empêche de renvoyer les
>   résultats. Si le problème persiste, contactez votre administrateur. - 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowGenericQueryException(String
>   operationName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1
>   webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String
>   operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query
>   query)     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query
>   query)     at SearchResultSP.SearchResultWP.SearchResultWP.GetData()

I'm disapointed and I don't understand why it doesn't work

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would dissect your query to determine the issue. Pare it down to a simple query. Remove the sorting, for example. Then watch the ULS Logs while the query executes. The SORTING processing has changed in 2013 and may be the root of your problem. There should be an error in ULS logs that tells you what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks i gonna check this when i'm in office. Do you have a exemple for the new sorting in 2013?

Comment: To begin with, you have to specify "sortable" as an attribute of your managed properties before the crawl.

Comment: all my meta are sortable but still doesn't work. When i put the switch for sorting in comment, the search works